# Equivalent dimensions for ga:adContent and ga:keyword in the Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics-api

We currently rely on using UTM parameters (utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_term, utm_content) for our Universal Analytics integration with the Google Analytics Core Reporting API and Multi-Channel Funnels APIs.

Are there plans to support UTM tags in GA4 properties and the Google Analytics Data API? I do see sessionSource, sessionMedium, and firstUserCampaignName listed in the dimensions list, which suggests utm_source, utm_medium, and utm_campaign can still be used. Is there an equivalent dimension for utm_content (ga:adContent in the Core Reporting API and mcf:adwordsAdContent in the MCF API) or utm_term (ga:keyword or mcf:keyword)?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be no equivalent dimensions for ga:keyword or ga:adContent in the Google Analytics Data API. I will try to find out more about this and update this question once I have more information.

Ilya
The Google Analytics Team

Comment: Thank you for investigating Ilya. It would be helpful to include equivalent dimensions or an alternative in the Google Analytics Data API.

Comment: Matt, although I cannot commit to specific timelines yet, but keyword/adContent dimensions are likely to be added to the Data API in the coming weeks. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Hi Ilya - in GA4 will googleAdsKeyword return the value from utm_term or is googleAdsKeyword only intended to show a keyword if Google Analytics is linked to a Google Ads account? Any update re: adContent would also be appreciated as that is a blocker for our organization. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @IlyaKuleshov, thank you for looking into this. Would you mind sharing any updates on this or pointing me where I can ask these questions?